# How to configure Database to delete everything in my database table whenever my application starts

Tags: c#

In my C# application, I want to delete everything in System.Data.Entity.Databas when my application starts and re-populate my data from scratch programically.

I see there is an Initalizer method. 
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer()

How can I implement my initializer to delete everything from scratch ?
and repopulate my data?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220411/entity-framework-delete-all-rows-in-table)

Comment: Wait, you want to wipe out a table in your database and repopulate it when the application starts? Then what's the point of putting data in the table in the first place? Regardless, this is a very broad question. If you're using EF, clear the container and save changes. If not, create a stored procedure and call it when the program starts.

Comment: Similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491869/drop-or-recreate-database-with-entity-framework-migrations-code-first)

Comment: Wouldn't be restore database from initial backup the simplest thing to do? I bet it will save you some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your schema is always the same (guess it is), why not a simple stored procedure which makes a Truncate on every table, or a simple list of plain text queries (started by ExecuteStoreCommand / ExecuteSqlCommand) to do the same Truncate at startup ?

Then you just have to repopulate, by the way you wish.